# Regex - Skipping a variabel amount of matches

Tags: c#, regex

```
<element>
<adresse>0x50</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>1  (153.00521703-PROTO)</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>49</wert>
</element>
<element>
<adresse>0x51</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>5</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>53</wert>
</element>
<element>
<adresse>0x52</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>3</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>51</wert>
</element>
<element>
<adresse>0x53</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>.</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>46</wert>
</element>
<element>
<adresse>0x54</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>0</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>48</wert>
</element>
<element>
<adresse>0x55</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>0</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>48</wert>
</element>
<element>
<adresse>0x56</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>5</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>53</wert>
</element>
<element>
<adresse>0x57</adresse>
<typ>byt</typ>
<faktor>1</faktor>
<einheit/>
<kommentar>2</kommentar>
<range/>
<wert>50</wert>
</element>​
```

I want to search for specific values in multiple `Textfile`.

I wrote an simple `Regex` like this which finds me anything between the words  typ> and \typ>

```
Regex RegTyp = new Regex(@"typ>(.*?)/typ>");
```

Now whenever I find the word "bit" it should read the NEXT eight matches you can find in the `textfile` with the `Regex`

```
Regex RegValue = new Regex(@"value>(.*?)/value>")
```

which finds me anything between the words  value> and \value>

I am trying to Programm it like this:

```
if (a.Equals("bit"))

//a defines my match

{Regex RegValue = new Regex(@"value>(.*?)/value>");

for(int i =0;i<8;i++)
{...
```

The Problem is my `Regex` for `RegValue` is now matching the complete text and not the NEXT 8 matches after I matched "bit" with RegTyp

Any help is useful 
Thank you

Comment: Your question is a **bit** unclear. Please clarify it with some more examples.

Comment: Are you working on XML using regex?

Comment: Its Kind of an XML file but not exactly its an own format

Comment: I have very big text files with data.
I want to convert the Information in a useful Format.

for example the text says:
<typ>bit</typ>
<value>0<\value>
<value>1<\value>
<value>1<\value>
<value>0<\value>
....and so on 8 times
this always occurs when <typ>bit</typ> is mentioned

Comment: Ok, outside the issues of inventing the wheel again and using the wrong tool, you need to offset the 8-match by the position of the triggering match.

Comment: After you edited your comment: What about that example is _not_ xml? Surround it with a root tag to make it valid and use Xml Tools you get for free out of the box.

Comment: So I build in a Counter that Counts the amount of matches?
How can I tell Regex to skip the counted amount of lines?
Which tool would be better?
I am sorry I am still new to c# and thought regex might be the best way to solve this problem

Comment: Unrelated : If you find yourself "and thought regex might be the best way to solve this problem" - reconsider. At least thrice. If it still seems to be the best fit - so be it.

Comment: the file has already an root tag but i am not able to read it like an XML file that why I tried to come up with an own solution

Comment: Match with offset see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ekkwhs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: To get the offset: [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx) class has Index and Length properties. So you would want to use index+length as an offset to your sub-match.

Comment: "file has already an root tag but i am not able to read it like an XML file" - maybe it's worth investigating in that direction: Why did it fail? I am pretty sure your solution will be much more stable if you could use XPath.

Comment: Can I define the index and the length with an variable?

Comment: The Editor that created this file is very old and written by an other Student 8 years ago. The file might have a lot of flaws

Comment: I don't understand. Your first regex search will give you a list of matches (class `Match`). Each of those instances have properties "Index" and "Length" set to the appropriate values. So you can `int offset = match.Index + match.Length;` and put offset into the subsequent Regex.Match

Comment: "A lot of flaws" in that it is not valid xml or in that it is corrupt?

Comment: I get that now I will see if it works

Comment: Post sample of text file. Regex is not always the best solution for parsing text.  Been parsing for over 40 years and only use RegEx where it make sense.

Comment: That it might be not a valid XML. As I said he wrote a complete Editor for those files so he has an unclean structure. 

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @jdweng basically every text is written in between the Parameters which are labeled with <> and <\> (for start and finish) .

I can't post a bigger sample as the site is not displaying them correctly

Comment: Post them in a snippet box (the one with <> in the icon).

Comment: @jdweng I managed to post a sample of the file

Comment: It seems to be perfectly valid XML, except that it's lacking the xml definition, and doesn't have a single root element around everything. But that's easily added in code if needed; just do something like `myText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><root>" + myText + "</root>"` and that should be solved.

Comment: I will try to Program this in c# and see if it becomes a valid XML file

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            new Element(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Element
    {
        public static List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
        public int address  { get; set;}
        public string typ  { get; set;}
        public int faktor  { get; set;}
        public string einheit  { get; set;}
        public string kommentar  { get; set;}
        public string range  { get; set;}
        public int wert  { get; set;}

        public Element() { }
        public Element(string filename)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "element")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("element");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement element = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

                    Element newElement = new Element();
                    Element.elements.Add(newElement);

                    newElement.address = int.Parse(((string)element.Element("adresse")).Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    newElement.typ = (string)element.Element("typ");
                    newElement.faktor = (int)element.Element("faktor");
                    newElement.einheit = (string)element.Element("einheit");
                    newElement.kommentar = (string)element.Element("kommentar");
                    newElement.range = (string)element.Element("range");
                    newElement.wert = (int)element.Element("wert");

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your program you saved me a lot of time and work :)

Comment: I moved the code around a little bit and put all the code into the class to make it easier to work with.